# Most efficient way of determining periods of availability for a given day for a mailbox

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Using Exchange Web Services, what is the most efficient way to get availability for a day?

I want to get periods of the day that appointments / meetings are scheduled for. I know I can do this by looping through all calendar items but I want to just look at one day as this will be a lot quicker than looping through many days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the availability service - GetUserAvailabilityRequest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563800(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: This is also wrapped up in the managed EWS component as GetUserAvailability. Thanks for your help Dmitry :)